# Show banner only on category pages

Tags: category, template, magento-1

I am trying to show banner on category pages only. Following is what I did yet

in page.xml

```
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category_banner" as="category_banner" template="catalog/category/category_banner.phtml" />
```

in category_banner.phtml

```
<?php if($_imageUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()): ?>
   <p class="category-image"><img src="<?php echo $_imageUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()) ?>" /></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

its working properly on category pages but its now showing on product pages as well. and on home page it gives me following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Category\View.php on line 44
```

Comment: Add your layout xml file code.

Answer (score 1):

Add you code under `<reference name="content">` under
`<catalog_category_default>` tag.

Which you can find on `catalog.xml` file.

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: I added this the code in catalog.xml file and now banner is showing on category page only but after breadcrum, How can I move it above banner so that page will show banner and then breadcrum and title ?

Comment: add `before="breadcrumbs"` on your code. So it will be `<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category_banner" as="category_banner" before="breadcrumbs" template="catalog/category/category_banner.phtml" />`

Comment: <reference name="content">
      <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category_banner" as="category_banner" before="breadcrumbs"  template="catalog/category/category_banner.phtml"/>

Comment: above code not working, still showing after breadcrum

Comment: `<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category_banner" as="category_banner" template="catalog/category/category_banner.phtml" before="breadcrumbs"/>` try this

Comment: don't forget to clear cache

Answer (score 1):

You have to write code inside theme `local.xml` file instead of `page.xml` file.
YOu have to place this code inside `<catalog_category_layered>` and `<catalog_category_default>` node.

```
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category_banner" as="category_banner" template="catalog/category/category_banner.phtml" before="breadcrumbs" />
```

Comment: I added this the code in catalog.xml file and now banner is showing on category page only but after breadcrum, How can I move it above banner so that page will show banner and then breadcrum and title ?

Comment: i have updated my answer. check again

Comment: what if i dont have local.xml file ? I copied page.xml and renamed it to local.xml is it ok or do i need to leave it blank ?

Comment: You have to create local.xml inside app/design/frontend/{package}/{themename}/layout folder

Answer (score 1):

Write you block inside `<catalog_category_default>` handle in your layout xml file.

if you write your block inside `<default>` handle it will get called on every page.

Better you write your code in either `local.xml` or `catalog.xml` by under above specified handle `<catalog_category_default>`

Answer (score 1):

Create local.xml in your theme layout add below code:

```
<catalog_category_default>
  <reference name="category.products">
    <block type="core/template" name="category_banner" as="category_banner" template="catalog/category/category_banner.phtml" />
  </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
  <reference name="category.products">
    <block type="core/template" name="category_banner" as="category_banner" template="catalog/category/category_banner.phtml" />
  </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this line correct?

```
<?php if($_imageUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()): ?>
```

should it not be

```
<?php if($_imageUrl **==** $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()): ?>
```

two equals

Comment: what are you trying to say buddy??

Comment: The comparison operator in your question has one equal instead of two